# How to update a mongodb document using email not id?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a nodeJs Application to execute CRUD operations. All are fine except update (I use email).

When I try via postman, it returns 202 - Ok, but when I check the document in MongoDb, the it's not being updated and it keeps the old value/firstname. I have been searching here, found some hints, but they didn't help

**crud_controller.js**:

```
exports.update_member = function(req, res) {

    var userEmail = req.body.email;

    User.update({ userEmail }, {$set: req.body}, {multi: true}, function(err, user) {
        console.log(`user: ${userEmail} req.body:  ${JSON.stringify(req.body)} );

        if (err) {
            return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Cannot Update User'});
        }       
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(404).json({success: false, msg: 'User not found'});
        }  
        else { 
            res.json({success: true, msg: 'User has been updated'}) 
        };
    });
};
```

I have been trying: **`{new:true}`** and other options found here on SO as an answer of few questions, but none of them did help.

Here is the console.log of node file:

```
user: ramirezrodgers@xxxx.com 
req.body: {"email":"ramirezrodgers@xxxx.xy","firstname":"test5"}
```

and I also get the succeeded response:

```
{success: true, msg: 'User has been updated'}
```

Actually, everything looks fine. Where am I  going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> { email: userEmail } do this in your code

```
 exports.update_member = function(req, res) {
    
        var userEmail = req.body.email;
    
        User.update({ email: userEmail }, {$set: req.body}, {multi: true}, function(err, user) {
            console.log(`user: ${userEmail} req.body:  ${JSON.stringify(req.body)}`);
    
            if (err) {
                return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Cannot Update User'});
            }       
            if (!user) {
                return res.status(404).json({success: false, msg: 'User not found'});
            }  
            else {
                return res.json({success: true, msg: 'User has been updated'});
            }
            
        });
    };
```

Comment: Ohh. My bad. How did I oversee this? Works fine now.